# Do google game services require the users to have a g+ account to enter lobby?

Tags: java, multiplayer, google-play-services, matchmaking

I've been reading [Google Game Services (GGS)](https://developers.google.com/games/services/) API about [multiplayer lobby/rooms](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer) and the documentation doesn't make it very clear if the users are required to sign in with a Google+ account (which I don't want).

The [web GGS SDK](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/clientsetup) mentions this:

> The simplest way to add a sign-in button to your page is to implement
>   the HTML-based sign-in button. For implementation details, see Adding
>   the HTML sign-in button to your page on the Google+ Sign-In
>   documentation.

What I am looking for is a simple way (service or library) to connect anonymous users together (matchmaking). 
My application being in Java, a Java compatible API is also needed.

**Can Google Game Services fit the bill or should I keep looking?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are required to sign in with a Google Plus account. It's possible to [use the leaderboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055235/do-i-need-google-sign-in-to-use-google-play-game-services) without requiring users to sign in. You won't be able to connect players without them having accounts. The service is free because it allows Google to collect data on its users (play trends, in app payments, social sharing, etc.), thus it requires the users to sign in.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I understand your point. Though, you can collect data about anonymous user, or user that you sign in using some OAuth scheme.